# sqlAlchemy: update element with one-many relation ship fails

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update a parent in a one-many relationship

```
class Episode(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=True, index=True)
    airdate = Column(Date, nullable=False, index=True)
    comment = Column(String, nullable=True, index=True)
    segments = relationship("Segment")

class Segment(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    episode_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("episode.id"), nullable=False)
    ...some normal keys
```

I fetch the current episode and then try to update it

```
existing_episode = db.query(Episode).filter(Episode.id == id)
existing_episode.update(episode.__dict__)
```

What happens is that I get a strange SQL error about

```
sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: episode_id
```

which comes from the SQL code also dumped:

```
[SQL: UPDATE episode SET id = episode_id=?, id=?, title=?, airdate=?, comment=? WHERE episode.id = ?]
[parameters: (None, 1, 'asdasd', '2015-05-18', 'NULL', 1)]
```

What I wonder is why the `episode_id` is there and how it came there ... the `dict` passed in does not contain `episode_id`, when I dump it I see

```
episode dict = >>{'id': 1, 'title': 'asdasd', 'airdate': datetime.date(2015, 5, 18), 'comment': 'NULL', 'segments': None}<<
```

So it seems to be related with the `relationship` and the `ForeignKey`, but this is how the docs say one should implement 1-n relationship: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: I cannot reproduce, please [edit] your post and add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that using the `__dict__` in

```
existing_episode.update(episode.__dict__)
```

creates the problem, since it contains a relationship that breaks the sql parser. Entering the hash directly with the required values only makes the code work.

See https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/8468 for a longer discussion.